# How to find the pager used by man?

Tags: linux

How to find the pager used by man command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From `man man` option(snippet below) -P to change pager and *default pager is `/usr/bin/less`*

> -P  pager
>                     Specify which pager to use.   This  option  overrides
>                     the  MANPAGER  environment  variable,  which  in turn
>                     overrides the PAGER variable.  By default,  man  uses
>                     /usr/bin/less -is.

Answer (score 4):

Alternately,

```
echo $PAGER
```

since the environment variable may have been changed unbeknownst to `man man`.